# How to loop through Azure Mobile Service Table using JavaScript in a Custom API

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I want to access all the rows in a table in Azure Mobile Service Custom API, extract particular columns' values and perform some operation on them. How do I syntactically do it in JavaScript?

What I have done till now is:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {    
var tables = request.service.tables;

var eventIdString=request.body.EventId;
var LongClientString = request.body.Longitude;
var LatClientString = request.body.Latitude;
var eventId = parseFloat(eventIdString);
var longClient = parseFloat(LongClientString);
var latClient = parseFloat(LatClientString);

var mssql = request.service.mssql;
var sql = "SELECT * FROM User";

var str="";

mssql.query(sql, {
    success: function(results) {
        for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
        {
            var longServerString = results[i].longitude;
            var latServerString = results[i].latitude;
            var longServer = parseFloat(longServerString);
            var latServer = parseFloat(latServerString);

            var distance = getDistanceInKm(latClient, longClient, latServer, longServer);

            if(distance<20)
            {
                str=str+results[i].name+",";
            } 
        }
    }});    

response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : str }); 

//calculating distace
function getDistanceInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
var a = 
Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c; // Distance in km
return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
return deg * (Math.PI/180)
} };
```

But I'm getting nothing in 'str'. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're not waiting for the result of the `mssql.query` call before using the `str` variable. Like almost everything in node.js-land, `query` is an asynchronous operation, so when it returns, the success callback has not been called yet.

Try moving the `response.send` call to inside the callback, and you should start seeing some results.

```
mssql.query(sql, {
    success: function (results) {
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            var longServerString = results[i].longitude;
            var latServerString = results[i].latitude;
            var longServer = parseFloat(longServerString);
            var latServer = parseFloat(latServerString);

            var distance = getDistanceInKm(latClient, longClient, latServer, longServer);

            if(distance < 20)
            {
                str = str + results[i].name + ",";
            }
        }
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : str });
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks @carlosfigueira. I overlooked that little detail.